# Matlab import HDF5 - Transposed

Tags: python, matlab, pandas, hdf5

I am saving a (6000 x 2000) matrix using pandas to HDF5 as follows:

```
   pd.to_hdf("myfile.hdf","mytable",format="table")
```

and read it back to Matlab with

```
  data = h5read("myfile.hdf","/mytable/table")
```

Strangely though, the matrix now is automatically transposed to a (2000 x 6000) matrix. It's of course easy to transpose back in Matlab, but is there a way to prevent this behavior from happening by default?

Comment: Probably caused by the difference in row/Column major order. I am afraid that it can't be avoided. (You can obviously transpose the matrix at the beginning if you don't want to do at the end but that wouldn't really be any different)

Comment: It's worth checking: when you use [`h5disp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/h5disp.html) on the file, what do you get for dataset `Size`?

Comment: h5disp gives the following (note, array size is 6296 x 1516 in reality, rather than 6000 x 2000 used in the explanation of the issue): 

Dataset 'table' 
    Size:  6296
    MaxSize:  Inf
    Datatype:   H5T_COMPOUND
        Member 'index':  H5T_STD_I64LE (int64)
        Member 'values_block_0':  H5T_ARRAY
            Size: 1516
            Base Type:  H5T_IEEE_F64LE (double)
    ChunkSize:  21
    Filters:  none